# Matplotlib - Restore Draggable Legend Position

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to restore legend location once a figure is removed and added again to canvas. Legend is generated using

```
leg=ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0.99,0.99) , loc='upper right')
leg.draggable(True,use_blit=True,update='bbox')
```

I'm using `update='bbox'` which updates the bbox location once legend is dragged.

When restoring I'm using `get_bbox_to_anchor` which gives me a `TransformedBbox`

If I don't drag the legend

```
TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.99, 0.99], [0.99, 0.99]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.125, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [12.975, 8.1375]]), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,  80.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))))
```

If I drag the legend

```
TransformedBbox(Bbox([[485382.883642, 190633.226933], [485382.883642, 190633.226933]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.125, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [12.975, 8.1375]]), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,  80.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))))
```

So now I have `bbox` and `transform` using

```
transformedbbox=leg.get_bbox_to_anchor()
bbox= transformedbbox.inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)
 # print bbox
 # Bbox(x0=485382.883642, y0=190633.226933, x1=485382.883642, y1=190633.226933)
transform= transformedbbox._transform
# print transform
# BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.125, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [12.975, 8.1375]]), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,  80.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   1.]]))))))
```

and I use both of them to restore the legend using `set_bbox_to_anchor` which accepts bbox and transform.

```
leg.set_bbox_to_anchor(bbox,transform)
```

But my legend is getting placed far away from the figure(miles away).

Most likely I'm making some mistake in extracting transform. What is the correct way to extract bbox and transform information for using with `set_bbox_to_anchor`.

**Update:**

(If `get_bbox_to_anchor` is supposed to give output in axes coordinate frame)

In method `def _update_bbox_to_anchor(self, loc_in_canvas)` of `Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py` file

If I replace line

```
tr = self.legend.axes.transAxes
```

with

```
tr = self.legend.axes.transAxes.inverted()
```

After dragging the legend `get_bbox_to_anchor` outputs:

```
TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.341489285295, 0.433591056494], [0.341489285295, 0.433591056494]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.125, 0.1], [0.9, 0.9]]), BboxTransformTo(TransformedBbox(Bbox([[0.0, 0.0], [12.975, 8.1375]]), Affine2D(array([[ 80.,   0.,   0.],
   [  0.,  80.,   0.],
   [  0.,   0.,   1.]])))))))
```

which clearly looks like points in axes coordinate system.

But there is a small offset in legend's position upon using the points.

Changing legend `loc` changes the direction and magnitude of shift.
(lowest for `lower left` and highest for `upper right`)

**Update 2**

Minimal Working example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig_dict=[]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(range(10), label='Test')
legend = ax.legend(loc='upper right',bbox_to_anchor=(0.99,0.99))
legend.draggable(True,use_blit=True,update='bbox')


fig.canvas.draw()

def on_scroll(event):
    print legend.get_bbox_to_anchor()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', on_scroll)

fig.show()
```

This example prints output of `get_bbox_to_anchor` on scrolling

compare the output of scroll after dragging the legend before and after making the change in method `def _update_bbox_to_anchor(self, loc_in_canvas)` of `Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py` file

by replacing the line

```
tr = self.legend.axes.transAxes
```

with

```
tr = self.legend.axes.transAxes.inverted()
```

Comment: I think you should assemle a [mcve] which shows the issue, such that people can reproduce it. Otherwise you'll be having a long monologue here.

Comment: Please read only the portion after Update heading... I have raised an issue on github also....[link](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8661)

Comment: Read only Update 2.... I have added an example..